# Trying to encode an image in base64 after resizing

Tags: php, xml, base64

In php, I'm trying to encode an image in base64 after a resize. When I encode it directly with no resize it's working fine

```
$bitmapNode = $dom->createElement( "bitmap" );
$bitmapNode->appendChild( $dom->createTextNode(base64_encode(file_get_contents($url)))  );
$root->appendChild( $bitmapNode );
```

But when I'm trying to do a resize before the encoding it doesn't work anymore and the content of the xml node is empty.

```
$image = open_image($url);
if ($image === false) { die ('Unable to open image'); }
// Do the actual creation
$im2 = ImageCreateTrueColor($new_w, $new_h);
imagecopyResampled($im2, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 256, 256, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
$bitmapNode = $dom->createElement( "bitmap" );
$bitmapNode->appendChild( $dom->createTextNode(base64_encode($im2)) );
$root->appendChild( $bitmapNode );
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$im2` is just a GD resource handle. it is NOT the image data itself. To capture the resized image, you'll have to save it and then base64_encode that saved data:

```
imagecopyresample($im2 ....);
ob_start();
imagejpeg($im2, null);
$img = ob_get_clean();
$bitmapNode->appendChild($dom->createTextNode(base64_encode($img)));
```

Note the use of output buffering. The GD image functions do not have a method to directly return the resulting image data. You can only write to a file, or output directly to the browser. So using the ob functions  lets you capture the data without having to resort to a temporary file.

Comment: +1 - Hopefully one day they'll improve the function so that you don't need to use output buffering!

Comment: @David: hopfully some day they'll put an object wrapper around the whole thing so you don't have to drag a handle around for every function call, either.

Comment: Nice, it's working. I would never have figure it out myself. Thanks !